# How to send IBM MQ message reliably if Destination is down?

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

i have to send a message to IBM queue. I have written a normal producer class to push the message to queue as :-

```
        Session session = queueConnection.createSession(true,
            QueueSession.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Destination destination =
            session.createQueue("test.queue");
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(destination);

            TextMessage message = session.createTextMessage("test");
            producer.send(message);

        // Close the session
        session.close();
```

Now, suppose due to some reason Queue which is present inside QueueManager is down or IBM MQ broker is down or there is a network issue which leads to send message failure.

Is there a mechanism in JMS/IBM MQ which can retry automatically to send the message ( basically retry mechanism ) and retry some defined number of times before finally give up to send the message to IBM MQ broker?

Answer (score 1):

IBM MQ JMS Client (other IBM MQ clients as well) has a feature wherein if a connection IBM MQ Queue Manager breaks for any reason, the client attempts to reconnect to queue manager till a specified amount of time. See here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_9.0.0/com.ibm.mq.dev.doc/q032520_.htm. You will need to configure connection factory to enable to re-connection.

For example, if connection to queue manager breaks while executing `producer.send` method, the IBM MQ JMS client automatically attempts to reconnect to queue manager and send the message.

In IBM MQ, a queue can not go down, it can become in-accessible though, for example if queue is full or put/get on queue has disabled etc.

Comment: Thanks for pointing to the link. But my use case is that application will be running inside TOMEE container. If queue is unavailable due to some reason, will the application be running inside TOMEE be able to auto re-connect using  setClientReconnectOptions ?

Comment: Yes, MQ JMS client will attempt to reconnect if if you have enabled reconnect options and a connection breaks.